# OpenERP 7 : How can I open a decoded file as a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, decode, openerp-7

I have a module which asks the user to give a csv file, with the binary field. So once the module has it, I decode it and write the result in a Temporary File, but then I can't open it as a CSV file : I will get the error "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found" because I'm trying to open a File Object. So how can I decode the file and then open it as a CSV file ?

Here is my code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from osv import fields, osv
import csv
import base64
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

class set_dates(osv.osv_memory):
    _name = "set.dates"

    _columns = {
        "donnees": fields.binary("Données", required=True)
    }

    def do_set(self, cr, uid, ids, data, context=None):

        this = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0])
        fileobj = TemporaryFile('w+')
        fileobj.write(base64.decodestring(this.donnees))

        fic = csv.reader(open(fileobj, "rb"))
        tab = list(fic)
        #...
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is on the line `fic = csv.reader(open(fileobj, "rb"))`

`open()` is complaining that its argument is a file object, instead of a string or buffer. That's because the variable `fileobj` is a `file` object, which was open with:

`fileobj = TemporaryFile('w+')`

You just have to replace:
`fic = csv.reader(open(fileobj, "rb"))` 
with:
`fic = csv.reader(fileobj)`

Comment: Indeed, it reads the file now, but I have a problem with the command tab = list(fic), after this the command print len(tab[0]) shows the error "IndexError: list index out of range", as if the conversion in csv wasn't complete and the file wasn't sorted in rows and columns

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen your data, I can't possibly comment! Try and debug by showing (printing) the content of your data first: `print fileobj.readlines()` for instance

Comment: It is private data, but it follows the basic model of a csv file with several rows with data separated with commas ("blablabla", 123, "etc" and others rows following the same model). So I tried to save the file and read it, it has the same disposition as the original csv file, but somehow when I make the csv.reader command, it seems like it doesn't read it like a csv file, maybe because it hasn't the .csv extension.

Comment: Try to print out some data from csv.reader, or iterate on it simply with `for r in fic` and `print(r)`...
Also check for quote characters, etc. 
And finally try and input some very simple data first, such as 2 columns and 1 line

Comment: @Armand feel free to mark the answer as accepted / +1 it if it helpd you with the specific original question. I'm happy with the ongoing discussion but it's going beyond the original ask :)